# Replace string and repeat for each variable Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, loops, variables, replace

I have a variable with this content

```
var PropertysIds = "1234,2345,3456"
```

What I need is that for each id I have separated by "," replace "REPLACEHERE" in the following content.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var GetListing = document.querySelector('.listing_wrapper[data-listid="REPLACEHERE"]');
    if ( GetListing ) { 
    var AddLabel = '<div title="Casa Segura" class="casa_segura2"></div>';      
    jQuery(GetListing).prepend(AddLabel);
    }
    else{}
</script>
```

The end result should be that script repeated three times but with the string "REPLACEHERE" replaced by each ","

Please Help!

Comment: Why do you use a mix of jQuery and non-jQuery style of coding?

Comment: Sorry I'm new to javascript, it's an array, I just used implode to give it the shape I want (just separated with ",")

Comment: You seem to speak of some PHP code? What you presented now (after the edit) is not an array, but a string.

Comment: I'm editing the functions.php of a Wordpress template so I mix Jquery, PHP, and Javascript, the point is that I need to make a kind of loop where the same cycle is repeated for each variable. I hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `split` to make the string an array, and then map each to a selector. Concatenate those selectors with a comma, and pass it to jQuery:

```
jQuery(
    PropertysIds.split(',')
                .map(id => `.listing_wrapper[data-listid="${id}"]`)
                .join(',')
).prepend(AddLabel);
```

Comment: You're my hero! its works, thanks